# Joint Casimir Invariants?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm a physicist so forgive me any improper use of terminology. This question is mostly me trying to find the correct math literature/terminology to learn about what I'm describing.

Suppose I have a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. This Lie algebra has some set of [Casimir invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_element), i.e. quantities that are conserved under the adjoint action by the corresponding Lie group.

Now consider the new Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}\oplus\mathfrak{g}$. I am interested in identifying joint invariants under the action of *the same* Lie group element on each "block" of the direct sum. I.e. what is invariant under $(U^\dagger\oplus U^\dagger)(g_1\oplus g_2)(U\oplus U)$ where $g_1, g_2\in\mathfrak{g}$ and $U, U^\dagger$ are in the Lie group?

If it matters, I'm particularly interested in the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(d)$ and the Lie group $SU(d)$. Mostly, I'm curious if there is mathematical literature on these sorts of invariants and if so, what terms I should be using to search for it.

Comment: As an intuitive/physical example, I would expect if my group is SO(3), I expect the angle between the vector representations of 2 elements of so(3) in some basis of SO(3) generators to be a conserved quantity.

Comment: Note that your description of the action via $U^\dagger$ only really makes sense in $SU(d)$ in general a Lie group acts on its Lie algebra via $X \mapsto UXU^{-1}$. Also I would call the "joint" action you describe the "diagonal" action.

Comment: It seems to me (although I am not confident that I have understood what you are looking for) that the invariants you are looking for are simply given by pairs of Casimir elements for $\mathfrak{g}$. If $(c_1,c_2)$ are a pair of elements in the centre of the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ then $(c_1,c_2)$ is invariant iff $c_1,c_2$ are separately invariant.

Comment: My apologies again for lack of good vocabulary usage (I suffer from the usual problem of physicists of thinking of Lie algebras and groups mostly as their matrix representations and am certainly messing up some terminology). Diagonal action does seem to be yielding some promising results. I'm also not quite clear yet if your second comment is all there is to it (my physical intuition of what I'm looking for suggests there should be other invariants), but this is a great starting point. Thank you!

I think, however, there should be other invariants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been rereading the examples you gave and I think I might be able to clear a few things up.

First things first, Casimir elements do not, in general, live in the Lie algebra but instead in its universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$. This thing is a infinite dimensional algebra with an identity element with the same generating relations as the Lie algebra but no limits as it were. It has the neat property that every representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ extends to a representation of $U(\mathfrak{g})$.

Now the Casimir invariants live in the centre of $U(\mathfrak{g})$ but we can also interpret them as symmetric polynomials in the adjoint representation. The first and most obvious of these is the quadratic one. This is nothing but the  Killing form under a different guise. The "angle" between two elements of $\mathfrak{so}_n $ should be nothing more than the Killing form of those two elements and so that is preserved by the simple adjoint action (no diagonal action needed here). I believe in the Physics case this is related in some way to the total angular momentum although my physics knowledge here is sketchy at the very best.

Comment: Thanks this is all quite helpful for straightening out a number of concepts I'm familiar with, but don't have a strong handle on. 

I do, however, think that you actually were right originally with your interpretation of my (mathematically imprecise) question. While perhaps not necessary for the $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ example it seems to be exactly what I need in general.

In particular, based on your comment I found the following paper which describes exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/000187087690027X

Comment: Or a little more specific and a little easier to read (for a physicist at least): https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.4446